# SQL queries on retrieving data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables, `Users` and `Question`:

```
User(Login,password,DOB,Country,Email,Name) Login is the Primary Key
Questions(QuestionID, Date&Time, Question,Login) QuestionID is the primary key
```

I wanted to retrieve those user's who have never post any question.
I tried to write it as:

```
SELECT * From Questions
WHERE Login IS NOT in Questions
```

IS it the correct way as i am trying to list out all the LoginID which doesn't not appear in the Question table. Therefore those are the ones who has never ask before. Thank you

Comment: If any of the answers below has solved your problem, then kindly accept it as answer. If no one does, then comment about the remaining issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following query will work:

```
Select *from users
where login not in (select distinct login from questions);
```

**Explanation:**

As you want detail of users, you should write `select *from users` instead of `select *from questions`.

Now, `where login not in (select distinct login from questions);`

Here, subquery returns all the login id which has posted questions and we'll display users with login ids that are `not in` the result set returned by subquery.

**EDIT:** To give further explanation as requested by OP

Let's take an example. I'll only take relevant columns in consideration.

**Users:**

```
Login | Name
--------------
 1    | A
--------------
 2    | B
---------------
 3    | C
```

**Questions:**

```
   QuestionID | Login
    --------------
     Q1       | 1
    --------------
     Q2       | 2
    ---------------
     Q3       | 2
```

So, we've 3 users with Login id 1,2 & 3. ALSO we've 3 questions and It has only 2 login id named 1 & 2 not to mention user with login id 2 asked two questions.

So the statement `select distinct login from questions` will give `1,2` as answer.

That means the whole where clause will look like as follows:

```
   where login not in (1,2)
```

So, our outer query will display info of only user with login 3.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I understand the fist part where SELECT * FROM users but i am still a bit confuse over the part for (SELECT DISTINCT Login FROM Question). Do you mid to explain bit more further? Thank You!

Comment: Sure. I'll explain it to you. Just give me a moment.

Comment: I've added explanation in answer, Please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select * from users
where not exists ( 
  select 1 
  from Question 
  where users.login = question.login)
```

You need to start from Users to get all those that are not in questions.

Users holds ALL users, Questions only those that had a question. If you output all from login that are not in questions youre golden.

Edit:

You select all users from User which `not exist` in Question.

`Select 1 from question where users.login = question.login` references the outer selects login and results in as many 1 as they have rows in Questions with the referenced login. (try `select 1 from users` - youll get as many rows as there are in users but instead of the "fields" you get 1s).

As soon as (at least) one 1 is reported the part `where not exists` excludes this row from being shown.

The answer you accepted creates a (unique, distinct) list  of `login` that are in Questions and checks if the `login` from user in `not in` this list.

Plenty ways to rome :o)

Other way would be [isaace`s](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5730949/isaace) statement:

```
select * 
from users U
left outer join questions Q
  on U.login = Q.login 
where Q.login is null
```

Left outer join joins ALL things in the left table with all things from the right table even if there is no match - the WHERE then only shows those that have Q.login == null, means, there is no match.
(keywourd OUTER can be left out, `left outer join == left join`)

Different SQL runs using different execution plans, with lots of data its sometimes wise to do one thing and not the other for performance or memory reasons...

Comment: Is there a  way to just list out LoginID which aren't in the questions table? It seems hard for me to understand the solution you have provided, as i am not very good in SQL, just a beginner. Thank you!

Comment: modified some explanations for the 3 presented solutions :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
select * from User u
left join Question q on q.Login = u.Login
where q.Login is null
```